# TextView с маской, как сделать

Tags: android, textview

Как сделать в TextView также как на изображение?
Может это маска какая?[image: изоброжение]

Comment: Вырезаешь string до @, заменяешь все кроме 1 буквы на доты, вставляешь назад.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void setSecretEmail(String email) {
    String star = "*";
    String dog = "@";
    int dogIndex = email.indexOf(dog);
    String prefix = email.substring(0, 1);
    String secret = email.substring(1, dogIndex);
    String postfix = email.substring(dogIndex);
    String stars = "";
    for(int x = 0; x < secret.length(); x++) {
        stars = stars + star;
    }
    String result = prefix + stars + postfix;
    yourTextView.setText(result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать разными методами.

1. Изменить стандартный механизм EditText, который используется для ввода пароля. В этом случаем можно воспользоваться [ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051962/change-edittext-password-mask-character-to-asterisk).
2. Если же вы решили использовать TextView, то надо придумывать логику, которая будет скрывать часть е-майл адреса. Как вариант, разделить строку на массив строк с разделением до "собаки", а дальше просто заменить символы в первой строки массива и обратно подставить в TextView.